# Unable to work with NEO 6m GPS module and Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi4

I need to obtain GPS coordinates using Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and I have found online that NEO 6m GPS module is used for RPIs. Unfortunately I am unable to get the GPS coordinates, and am getting some output instead.

I have searched for similar tutorials and have been only able to get tutorials of NEO 6m with RPI 3 model instead. I have tried to use them for RPI 4 but with no success. I have been getting the following output. [output of gps module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYPgI.png)